# SOAPUI SOAP Mocking error : Prefix can't begin with XML: XMLSchema-instance

Tags: xml, unit-testing, soap, soapui, vmware

I'm trying to mock some scenarios for Vmware vSphere Vcenter SOAP API (VMware-vSphereSDK-6.5.0 downloaded here: https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?productId=614&downloadGroup=VS-MGMT-SDK65).

I could mock several API operations until I ran into a problem as the WSDL refers to a namespace that generates an error apparently due to the following statement:

```
<selectSet XMLSchema-instance:type="TraversalSpec" xmlns:XMLSchema-instance="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Here is the exception thrown

```
ERROR:com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.DispatchException:   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Prefix can't begin with XML: XMLSchema-instance
   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.DispatchException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Prefix can't begin with XML: XMLSchema-instance
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchPostRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:242)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:114)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockRunner.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockRunner.java:144)
at com.eviware.soapui.monitor.JettyMockEngine$ServerHandler.handle(JettyMockEngine.java:604)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector$SslConnection.run(SslSocketConnector.java:713)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Prefix can't begin with XML: XMLSchema-instance
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3474)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parse(Locale.java:712)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:696)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:683)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:208)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject$Factory.parse(XmlObject.java:633)
at com.eviware.soapui.support.xml.XmlUtils.createXmlObject(XmlUtils.java:183)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.AbstractMockRequest.getRequestXmlObject(AbstractMockRequest.java:297)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchPostRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:193)
... 16 more
```

Here is the full body of the request for the operation of API that fails on SOAP UI (and obviously work on vSphere):

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Body>
    <RetrieveProperties xmlns="urn:vim25">
        <_this type="PropertyCollector">propertyCollector</_this>
        <specSet>
            <propSet>
                <type>Folder</type>
                <pathSet>name</pathSet>
                <pathSet>childType</pathSet>
            </propSet>
            <propSet>
                <type>Datacenter</type>
                <pathSet>name</pathSet>
            </propSet>
            <propSet>
                <type>VirtualMachine</type>
                <pathSet>name</pathSet>
            </propSet>
            <propSet>
                <type>Network</type>
                <pathSet>name</pathSet>
            </propSet>
            <propSet>
                <type>ComputeResource</type>
                <pathSet>name</pathSet>
                <pathSet>resourcePool</pathSet>
            </propSet>
            <propSet>
                <type>ClusterComputeResource</type>
                <pathSet>name</pathSet>
                <pathSet>resourcePool</pathSet>
            </propSet>
            <propSet>
                <type>Datastore</type>
                <pathSet>name</pathSet>
            </propSet>
            <objectSet>
                <obj type="Folder">group-d1</obj>
                <skip>true</skip>
                <selectSet XMLSchema-instance:type="TraversalSpec" xmlns:XMLSchema-instance="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <type>Folder</type>
                    <path>childEntity</path>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </selectSet>
            </objectSet>
        </specSet>
    </RetrieveProperties>
</Body>
```

My view is that this is an interpretation of the XML specs related to checking xml namespace correct syntax which was discussed and apparently fixed in that bug report (in a jdom context): https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/issues/126

Indeed, in their api, vmware folks refer to a namespace starting with XML (XMLSchema-Instance) and maybe should not (I'm not enough an XML expert to judge) but the specs https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#xmlReserved seems to cleary say that this MUST NOT be treated as an error.

Any idea on how to bypass (or fix) this issue is welcome.
Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The first edition of the XML Namespaces recommendation simply said that prefixes starting "xml" were reserved for use in future specifications; it didn't say what parsers should do if such prefixes were encountered.

Some products interpreted the rule by rejecting documents containing such a prefix. That would confound the intent of reserving them because if any new standard adopted such a name, documents using that name would not work with old software. So in the second edition of XML Namespaces, it was clarified what the rule meant: applications should not use such names, but parsers should not reject them.

But of course that was too late; software was already out there with a different interpretation of the rules, and some of it has not been updated.

How to solve the problem? You either have to change the document, or change the software. I would try putting the document through an XSLT transformation that changes the prefix.

Comment: Thx Michael for your answer. I'm writing a mockup of the API so if I change it then application invoking it won't work and the whole purpose is to test  an application that interacts with that API. My only possibility is to change the software or eventually to discover that someone already ran into that pb and that a bypass was develop somewhere under the form of a flag to disable such checking... Anyway thx for your answer, it kind of confirm my thoughts so I know now in which direction to head to hopefully fix it or bypass it.